# How to give every year a number for unique players

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Is there a option to give every year a number for unique player in R?
example:

```
        playerID yearID stint teamID   lgID   POS     G    PO     A     E    DP score
       <chr>  <chr> <chr> <fctr> <fctr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  aardsda01   2004     1    SFN     NL     P    11     0     0     0     0   0.0
2  aardsda01   2006     1    CHN     NL     P    45     1     5     0     1   7.5
3  aardsda01   2007     1    CHA     AL     P    25     2     4     1     0   3.5
4  aardsda01   2008     1    BOS     AL     P    47     3     6     0     0   9.0
5  aardsda01   2009     1    SEA     AL     P    73     2     5     0     1   7.5
6  aardsda01   2010     1    SEA     AL     P    53     2     3     1     0   2.0
7  aardsda01   2012     1    NYA     AL     P     1     0     0     0     0   0.0
8  aardsda01   2013     1    NYN     NL     P    43     1     5     0     0   7.5
9  aardsda01   2015     1    ATL     NL     P    33     0     1     1     0  -1.0
10 aaronha01   1954     1    ML1     NL    LF   105   205     4     6     0  -9.0



        playerID yearID stint teamID   lgID   POS     G    PO     A     E    DP score  value
       <chr>  <chr> <chr> <fctr> <fctr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <chr>
1  aardsda01   2004     1    SFN     NL     P    11     0     0     0     0   0.0     1
2  aardsda01   2006     1    CHN     NL     P    45     1     5     0     1   7.5     2
3  aardsda01   2007     1    CHA     AL     P    25     2     4     1     0   3.5     3
4  aardsda01   2008     1    BOS     AL     P    47     3     6     0     0   9.0     4
5  aardsda01   2009     1    SEA     AL     P    73     2     5     0     1   7.5     5
6  aardsda01   2010     1    SEA     AL     P    53     2     3     1     0   2.0     6
7  aardsda01   2012     1    NYA     AL     P     1     0     0     0     0   0.0     7
8  aardsda01   2013     1    NYN     NL     P    43     1     5     0     0   7.5     8
9  aardsda01   2015     1    ATL     NL     P    33     0     1     1     0  -1.0     9
10 aaronha01   1954     1    ML1     NL    LF   105   205     4     6     0  -9.0     1
```

The `value` Column is what I want.
Is there a option in R to do this???

Thanks,

Niek

Comment: It's better to post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can:

```
df %>% group_by(playerID) %>% mutate(value=1:n()) %>% ungroup
```

This little pipe :

1. groups your `data.frame` (let's say it's named `df`) based on `playerID`
2. then creates an additional column (here named `value` but you can change this) filled with integers (a much needed as they are rows in every group)
3. ungroups your `data.frame` once this is done.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes thanks, it works!!!! thanks for your help!